# What is the 'default' part for an imported Node.js module, generated from Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

In a typescript file I have a import of the filesystem and path Node modules. I use them in a pretty standard way, like:

`const workDir = path.join(outputDir, "process-specs");`.

When I transpile that using `tsc` it generates this line instead:

`var workDir = path_1.default.join(outputDir, "process-specs");`

The problem with that is the additional `default` member of the path module variable. I don't see it in the Node.js [path documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and wonder why tsc adds that and what this is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's aping the default export of es2015 modules: when you do `import foo from 'foo';` you are [importing the default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Description) of the foo module.

```
// foo.ts
export default foo;

// otherfile.ts
import foo from 'foo';
```

vs a named export

```
// foo.ts
export foo;

// otherfile.ts
import { foo } from 'foo';
```

If this is only running in node.js and not the browser you can just use `require` like normal, e.g. `const fs = require('fs');`. You'll need to install node typings so the compiler understands it:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Answer (score 0):

`allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in tsconfig.json is why default was generated for tsc. and `importHelpers`, `esModuleInterop` assume more advanced way to use.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to say here. Can you reformulate your answer to show better how it relates to my question?

Comment: @MikeLischke `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in `tsconfig.json` is why `default` was generated by tsc.

Comment: OK, I see. Maybe you should write it that way in your answer. As it is now, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @MikeLischke sorry for my poor english. i am chinese.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking care!